# AS3 Delay Timer Execute and Start Timer

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, adobe

Hello I have a ActionScript 3.0 project and I have a timer that is running on 1000 millisecond intervals.  I would like to delay this timer for 1500 milliseconds perform an action and start the timer again after the delay.  I thought I could do this easily, but I'm having trouble, would it be better to stop the timer and perform the action and then listen for the action to be completed to start the timer again?
If you have time, I would appreciate the help.
Thank you,
Scientific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question, why not something like this? (UNTESTED CODE)

```
yourTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, itIsTime);

function itIsTime(evt:TimerEvent):void {
  yourTimer.stop();
  yourTimer.reset();
  if(yourTimer.delay == 1500){
    //Do your stuff
    ...
    yourTimer.delay = 1000;
    yourTimer.start();
  } else {
    //Do your stuff
    ...
    yourTimer.delay = 1500;
    yourTimer.start();
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could use 2 timers, but the idea is the same, after 1000 do one thing, after 1500 do something different, controlling when each timer goes off with the other timer's listener function.

Comment: Hello ToddBFisher, thank you for responding, I like the looks of this, I'll test it out now thank you.